# Accordion not working Javascript (Cannot read property)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Helo all, I have a simple accordion and I want to show/hide on click content from the div. So far I achieve that my code add active class and that works well, the problem is with this `show` class. Console thorws me an error, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null`

This is my code

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var panel = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');

for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    var setClasses = !this.classList.contains('active');
    setClass(acc, 'active', 'remove');
    setClass(panel, 'show', 'remove');

    if (setClasses) {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show", 800);
    }
  }
}

function setClass(els, className, fnName) {
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].classList[fnName](className);
  }
}
```

```css
  div.panel {
  display: none;
  transition: 4.6 ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.panel.show {
  display: block !important;
```

```html
<p><button class="accordion">▼ Title 1</button></p>

<div class="panel">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Title
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>aaaaa</li>
      </ul>
  </ul>
</div>

<p><button class="accordion">▼ Title 2</button></p>

<div class="panel">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Title
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem 1</li>
        <li>aaaaa</li>
      </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can somebody try to help me with this? Thank you all

Comment: May I ask, why you are not using the jQuery functions for DOM access?

Comment: Because we are in the year 2021 @OdaYukimura xD

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Calm down, this question is tagged as jQuery.... and it's 2020

Comment: Yeah, I know. Was just a pun @OdaYukimura haha. Don't take me wrong. I still use jQuery on some projects.

Comment: @OdaYukimura Oh duck! I was writting 2020 and thought "no, it's 2021. I don't know what year I'm on". So yeah, definitely I don't know what year I'm on hahaha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are looking for `this.nextElementSibling` on a button that is inside a `<p>` element, so don't has any sibling next to it:

[image]

The button is a lone child inside his parent `<p>` so has no siblings.

The way you have your code, the easy thing to do is to look for the `<p>` sibling, so:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var panel = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');

for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    var setClasses = !this.classList.contains('active');
    setClass(acc, 'active', 'remove');
    setClass(panel, 'show', 'remove');

    if (setClasses) {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show", 800); // nextElementSibling of the parentNode.
    }
  }
}

function setClass(els, className, fnName) {
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].classList[fnName](className);
  }
}
```

```css
  div.panel {
  display: none;
  transition: 4.6 ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.panel.show {
  display: block !important;
```

```html
<p><button class="accordion">▼ Title 1</button></p>

<div class="panel">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Title
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>aaaaa</li>
      </ul>
  </ul>
</div>

<p><button class="accordion">▼ Title 2</button></p>

<div class="panel">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Title
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem 1</li>
        <li>aaaaa</li>
      </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works! Change only HTML with this:

```
<div>
    <button class="accordion">▼ Title 1</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <ul>
            <li>
                Title
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem</li>
                    <li>aaaaa</li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <button class="accordion">▼ Title 2</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <ul>
            <li>
                Title
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem 1</li>
                    <li>aaaaa</li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```